# IBM Worklight - wljq.js Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am getting this error when i run my project in android emulator:

```
file:///data/data/com.Home/files/www/default/worklight/wljq.js: Line 8002 : Uncaught Reference
Error: ibmweb is not definedfile:///data/data/com.Home/files/www/default/worklight/wljq.js: Line 8002 : Uncaught Reference
Error: ibmweb is not defined.
```

i am using ww.js file to support the mobile and desktop version (V17e)

Comment: Your post was not clear at all as to what you're trying to do.  I edited your question to try to make it a little more clear, but hoping you can add some more detail or background information so we can help you

Comment: This looks like a duplicate... of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233493/dojo-is-not-defined-ibmweb-is-not-defined-in-worklight-application

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate, but with the mention of a certain v17 incarnation, you're giving away IBM internal information. Try to keep questions like this as vague as possible when it comes to company specifics. 
Additionally, v17 was not meant for this purpose. Don't use www.js in your mobile project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your app in your eclipse using worklight simulator.